# Create a vbs file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This is the vbs file:

```
set w = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

W.Run chr^(34^) & "explore.bat" & chr^(34^), 0

echo set w= Nothing
```

(it will run a batch file, but hidden in the background)

I tried a suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471152/9240845)... This is my bat file so far (which is *supposed* to make the vbs file - **not** open it):

```
(
 echo set w = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

 echo W.Run chr^(34^) & "explore.bat" & chr^(34^), 0

 echo set w= Nothing
)>"1623.vbs"
```

This doesn't work, it ends up opening `explore.bat` (it shouldn't, it should just make the vbs file). I want to just make the vbs file.

I may have this all wrong (I'm very new to this), looking for any advice.

---

I also tried using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30877300/9240845) and didn't get anywhere (since it's multiple lines)

Comment: You need to escape the ampersands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the issue is not escaping the ampersands, you could have also avoided it altogether by avoiding using `Chr(34)` to begin with:

```
(
 echo set w = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

 echo W.Run """explore.bat""", 0

 echo set w= Nothing
)>"1623.vbs"
```

Your `Run` command will pass **explore.bat** as a *single* double-quote (`"explore.bat"`).

Essentially, you are *quoting* the quotation marks, the same way you would have quoted the string a: `"a"`. If you were to replace **a** with the double-quote **"**, you would have `"""`. *(essentially just imagine the middle quotation mark as the letter a from the previous example to visualize why this works)*.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to escape the "&" symbol. Below is the solved version

```
(
 echo set w = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)

 echo W.Run chr^(34^) ^& "explore.bat" ^& chr^(34^), 0

 echo set w= Nothing
)>"1623.vbs"
```